# LSTM Network Inputs

Tags: input, label, lstm

While I was reading this https://blog.aidangomez.ca/2016/04/17/Backpropogating-an-LSTM-A-Numerical-Example/, I cannot understand the labels of the given  example.

x_0 = [1 2]^T  with label: 0.5,  x_1=[0.5 3]^T with label: 1.25, where T is the transpoze.

These x_0 and x_1 are two dimensional timesteps for the given time series. How can they have different labels? Shouldn't they have a common label that corresponds to a real output? In my opinion, for the time series that consists of x_0 and x_1 should have one common label. What is the meaning of the label for x_0 and label for the x_1?

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: The example seems to model a time series regression (given features for this time step, predict a corresponding value), where x_0 and x_1 represent 2 data points (at different time steps), thus it can have different values (labels). I think you are confused because you are thinking of it as a time series classification, where you take in a series of time steps, and produce 1 single label for the entire sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Toukenize. Yes, you are right. I think that there is one time series that has member x_0 and x_1, and they should be used to predict one label. I still cannot understand the point you explained. If x_0 and x_1 are the time steps of the input time series, how can it has a label for each time steps. I cannot understant the label of a time step, I think there should be a label for the time series.

Comment: What you think : 1 data point has multiple time steps and 1 label; What the example shows: 1 data point only has 1 time step and 1 label.